# Designer not updating with new controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp.net/vb.net project. There are many pages with controls on them that work just fine.  Now I have a page that I added a couple of new div tags to and they are not showing in the designer and the code behind is not recognizing them.  I am using VS 2013 Version 12.0.21005.1 REL.  Also, I have done everything listed on this site http://www.codingdefined.com/2014/07/aspnet-how-to-regenerate-designercs.html.  However, nothing has worked so far.  I need some other suggestions on how to fix this problem, besides restarting my whole project.

Comment: Try rebuilding the project

Comment: I have rebuilt it, I ran build, I cleaned it.  I have done all the suggestions that I could possibly find and most of them more than once and more than one way.

Comment: And would you suggest to rebuild the project  as a joke thinking that I might not know what rebuild is?

Comment: Not as a joke. As a genuine suggestion

Comment: ok.  Sorry, I just thought maybe because of my low reputation on here that someone might be thinking I don't know much and then suggest rebuild it as joke thinking I would literally rebuild the entire project.

Comment: Do the controls that you want to see in code-behind have the runat="server" attribute in markup?

Comment: Yes, runat ="server" is there.  I have tried using FindControl.  I have defined the control in the code and then tried using FindControl.  But nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that there was a missing end tag.  I had to declare the div in the designer and then used FindControl.  Now it works.